# How do I actually USE this Lightning Network?

Tags: lightning-network

https://lightning.network/

I've clicked every link. There is no download. Not even some beta CLI thing which requires Bitcoin Core to function, or anything whatsoever.

If this is a thing and people are allegedly making "more money running a channel than I do at my day job", why is it that it doesn't seem to have anything to actually, you know, *use*?

This is actually a recurring question I have for many of these "crypto projects". They seem like utter vaporware with nothing to actually download and run and *use*. And yet, at the same time, I keep seeing people claim that it's this big thing and tons of people are already using it.

But how can they be using it when the official website has nothing whatsoever to use in practice?

Comment: It isn't safe to assume https://lightning.network/ is the official website for the Lightning Network. Just as we shouldn't assume https://dollar.com is the official website for the US Dollar. Bitcoin.com certainly is not the official website for Bitcoin and Blockchain.com is certainly not the official website for Blockchain technology.

Answer (score 3):

> https://lightning.network/
> I've clicked every link. There is no download. Not even some beta CLI thing which requires Bitcoin Core to function, or anything whatsoever.

https://docs.lightning.engineering/community-resources/resource-list

> If this is a thing and people are allegedly making "more money running a channel than I do at my day job", why is it that it doesn't seem to have anything to actually, you know, use?

Lightning Routing: Building a New Economy (Presentation with Q&A by Alex Bosworth | Saturday 27th March, 07:00pm CET): https://wiki.fulmo.org/wiki/Self-organized_Sessions_March_2021

> This is actually a recurring question I have for many of these "crypto projects". They seem like utter vaporware with nothing to actually download and run and use. And yet, at the same time, I keep seeing people claim that it's this big thing and tons of people are already using it.

Not sure about other projects, LN is doing better every month with development in different implementations, wallets, services, exchanges, usage and other [LApps](https://www.lapps.co/)

Answer (score 3):

I think one might need to do a bit more research than looking at a single site before declaring a whole ecosystem a fad. If you widen your search a bit, you will find that even the Lightning Network [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Network) lists implementations, either "lightning network beginner" or "lightning network getting started" finds a list of articles and videos that explains exactly what you are asking here, and "lightning network wallet" finds me e.g. this [list of 31 wallets](https://lightningnetworkstores.com/wallets).

If all of that is a bit of a flood of content, you could get started with Jameson Lopp's Lightning resource overview:
https://www.lopp.net/lightning-information.html